# Missing required property 'tabId'

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In the *background.js* I have a listener that is supposed to check if the page is fully loaded and then run a content script:

```
console.log('background.js started');
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tab.Id, allFrames: true },
        files: ['findname.js'],
      });
    console.log('script execution started')
});
```

But it returns an error:

> Error at parameter 'injection': Error at property 'target': Missing
> required property 'tabId'

I've tried to solve this by creating a variable "tabId" and assigning it with the id of the active tab.
The best thing I've found for this is

```
const tabId = chrome.tabs.get(tabId);
```

but it doesn't work either.

I'll appreciate your help!

Comment: Check the documentation: the parameter is not `tab` but `details` which contains `tabId` inside.

Comment: here's the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-executeScript) about executeScript() method — there's nothing about  `details`  parameter. 

which part of the documentation are you referring to?

Comment: and this is an [example](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#programmatic) — they don't use details parameter either:

    `chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {chrome.scripting.executeScript({target: { tabId: tab.id },files: ['content-script.js']});`

can you give me the link to the part you are referring to please?

Comment: The parameter `tab` refers to webNavigation listener, see the documentation for this API.

Comment: I have the exact same problem at the moment. @3103344 did you manage to figure it out since this was posted?

Comment: No, I didn't :(

Comment: The issue with mine was I was trying to target: tab.id within the chrome.runtime.onInstalled function. Seems like this is not supported.

Once I moved it to the chrome.runtime.onClicked function, it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

looking at all the fields of the object the field is actually tabId.

```
target: {
            tabId: tab.tabId,
            allFrames: true,
        },
```